# How to reset values of dependent children when select changed in a parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

I have a bunch of dropdowns in a form and I'm trying to reset those which are not dependent on picked option from "top" dropdown. For example, there is a dropdown "Gender:" with male/female and blank(default) option.

Now, when I first pick male, I get children (dropdowns and fields) which are shown when option "male" is picked. I continue adding info, selecting options on those children and when I come to the end, if I change "male" to "female", all the info I entered (including selected options of dropdown children) should be reset to default ie. blank values.

All these dropdowns are in the same form, so I can't just call

```
$('#form')[0].reset();
```

on his id. I tried it and it doesn't work, because it resets parent as well.

HTML looks like this

```
 <div id="questionsForm">
  <div id="question-6">
        <label>Gender:</label>
        <select>
            <option value="0"></option>
            <option value="male">Male</option>
            <option value="female">Female</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div id="question-7">
        <label>Question that should be shown once male is selected</label>
        <select>
            <option value="0"></option>
            <option value="yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="no">No</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div id="question-8">
        <label>Question that should be shown once female is selected</label>
        <select>
            <option value="0"></option>
            <option value="yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="no">No</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <!-- Question which should be shown once female is selected and answer Yes in question 8 is picked -->
    <div id="question-9">
        <label>Question</label>
        <select>
            <option value="0"></option>
            <option value="yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="no">No</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

edit: I also have JSON like this:

```
        {
        "Id": 6,
        //dependant answer(s)
        "DependantAnswers": [{
                "QuestionId": 1,
                "answer": ""
            }]
        },
        {

        "Id": 7,
        //dependant answer(s)
        "DependantAnswers": [{
                "QuestionId": 6,
                "answer": "male"
            }]
        },
        {

        "Id": 8,
        //dependant answer(s)
        "DependantAnswers": [{
                "QuestionId": 6,
                "answer": "female"
            }
            ]
        },
        {

        "Id": 9,
        //dependant answer(s)
        "DependantAnswers": [{
                "QuestionId": 6,
                "answer": "female"
            },
            {
                "QuestionId": 8,
                "answer": "yes"
            }
        ]
    },
```

and I filter questions dependent on questionId but which have different answer to array called toHideQuestions and when I try resetting their value and hide them, they just get hidden, but the value of selected option stays the same. Here is the code with which I iterate:

```
$.each(toHideQuestions, function (index, question) {
            $("#question-" + question.Id).val('');
            $("#question-" + question.Id).hide();

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add some custom attributes to your HTML elements, which define the dependency rules. This will allow more generic code.

Here is the result:

```js
$("#questionsForm select").click(function refreshVisibility() {
    $("[data-show-when]").each(function () {
        // Get selector that should return something for this question to
        // be visible.
        var question = $(this).attr('data-show-when');
        // Determine if current question should be cleared or visible:
        var visible = $(question).length > 0;
        // Clear if needed, and set visibility
        if (!visible) $('select', this).val('');
        $(this).toggle(visible);
    });
}).click();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="questionsForm">
    <div id="question-6">
        <label>Gender:</label>
        <select>
            <option value="0"></option>
            <option value="male">Male</option>
            <option value="female">Female</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div id="question-7" data-show-when="#question-6 option:selected[value=male]">
        <label>Question that should be shown once male is selected</label>
        <select>
            <option value="0"></option>
            <option value="yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="no">No</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div id="question-8" data-show-when="#question-6 option:selected[value=female]">
        <label>Question that should be shown once female is selected</label>
        <select>
            <option value="0"></option>
            <option value="yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="no">No</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <!-- Question which should be shown once female is selected and answer Yes in question 8 is picked -->
    <div id="question-9" data-show-when="#question-8 option:selected[value=yes]">
        <label>Question</label>
        <select>
            <option value="0"></option>
            <option value="yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="no">No</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Alternative: object with rules

In comments you mentioned you have an object that specifies all dependency rules. In that case you don't need the HTML attributes, and can use that object for implementing these rules:

```js
var rules = [{
    "Id": 7,
    //dependant answer(s)
    "DependantAnswers": [{
        "QuestionId": 6,
        "answer": "male"
    }]
}, {
    "Id": 8,
    //dependant answer(s)
    "DependantAnswers": [{
        "QuestionId": 6,
        "answer": "female"
    }]
}, {
    "Id": 9,
    //dependant answer(s)
    "DependantAnswers": [{
        "QuestionId": 6,
        "answer": "female"
    }, {
        "QuestionId": 8,
        "answer": "yes"
    }]
}];

$("#questionsForm select").click(function refreshVisibility() {
    rules.forEach(function (questionRule) {
        // Check if all dependencies have the needed answers:
        var show = questionRule.DependantAnswers.every(function (dependency) {
            return $('select', '#question-' + dependency.QuestionId).val() == dependency.answer;
        });
        // Get question element and set its visibility
        $('#question-' + questionRule.Id).toggle(show);
    });
    // Clear value of hidden questions:
    $("#questionsForm select").not(':visible').val('');
}).click();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="questionsForm">
    <div id="question-6">
        <label>Gender:</label>
        <select>
            <option value="0"></option>
            <option value="male">Male</option>
            <option value="female">Female</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div id="question-7">
        <label>Question that should be shown once male is selected</label>
        <select>
            <option value="0"></option>
            <option value="yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="no">No</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div id="question-8">
        <label>Question that should be shown once female is selected</label>
        <select>
            <option value="0"></option>
            <option value="yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="no">No</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <!-- Question which should be shown once female is selected and answer Yes in question 8 is picked -->
    <div id="question-9">
        <label>Question</label>
        <select>
            <option value="0"></option>
            <option value="yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="no">No</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As you can see, discussing code in comments is not ideal. You could add this information in your question.

Comment: No problem. I added a solution based on that rules-object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#question-6 select").change(function(){
   $("#question-7, #question-8, #question-9").hide();

   if($("option:selected",this).val() === "male")
   {
      $("#question-7").show();
   }
   else if($("option:selected", this).val() === "female")
   {
      $("#question-8, #question-9").show();
   }
});
```